# Из String [ ] в byte[ ] - C#

Tags: c#

Всем привет!
Опишу суть проблемы есть массив string в который записаны адреса байтов по типу:

```
string [] MyString = new string[8];
MyString [0]="0b00000000";
MyString [1]="0b00111100";
MyString [2]="0b01100110";

........

и тд.
```

Надо данные значения записать в массив байт (так как требуется сделать операцию сдвига влево над этими значениями)
то есть :

```
byte [] MyByte = new byte [8];
MyByte [0]=0b00000000;
MyByte [1]=0b00111100;
MyByte [2]=0b01100110;
```

Уважаемые форумчане прошу помочь новичку!

Comment: Может все таки значения байтов а не адреса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так:

```
string[] MyStrings = new string[3];
MyStrings[0]="0b00001000";
MyStrings[1]="0b00010000";
MyStrings[2]="0b00100000";

var bytes = MyStrings.Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(2, 8), 2)).ToArray();
```

и обратно в строки

```
var newStrings = bytes.Select(b => $"0b{Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')}").ToArray();
```

Но если вы избавитесь от префикса `0b` в исходных строках будет немного проще:

```
string[] MyStrings = new string[3];
MyStrings[0]="00001000";
MyStrings[1]="00010000";
MyStrings[2]="00100000";

var bytes = MyStrings.Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 2)).ToArray();

var newStrings = bytes.Select(b => Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')).ToArray();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!Только вот нужно теперь элементы этого массива побитово сдвигать на 1 бит влево, а методы которые я использовал ранее для сдвига больше не работают :).Незнаю что делать

Comment: @Baba_Jaga https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/left-shift-operator